# Grunt wiredep not wiring some bower components

Tags: bower, yeoman, grunt-wiredep

I am using yeoman webapp generator to generate a template to kick start of my work. At this moment, my bower.json looks like this

```
  {
    "name": "sample-project",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "bootstrap-sass": "~3.3.5",
      "modernizr": "~2.8.3",
      "fontawesome": "~4.3.0",
      "jquery.smooth-scroll": "~1.5.5",
      "animate.css": "~3.3.0",
      "jquery.appear": "*"
    },
    "overrides": {
      "bootstrap-sass": {
        "main": [
          "assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss",
          "assets/fonts/bootstrap/*",
          "assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "chai": "~3.0.0",
      "mocha": "~2.2.5"
    }
  }
```

Now, in cmd prompt I type this while grunt watch is running

```
bower install bootstrap-datepicker -S
```

Then I found `"bootstrap-datepicker": "~1.4.0"` is inserted into the dependencies section, then

```
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

will be automatically wiredep into my index.html, it becomes this

```
  <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
  <!-- bower:js -->
     .
     .
     <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
```

Then I try to install another bower component to my webapp

```
bower install country-region-selector -S
```

The next thing happens is I found `"country-region-selector": "~0.1.8"` is under dependencies section of bower.json like bootstrap-datepicker, however the corresponding

```
<script src="bower_components/country-region-selector/dist/crs.min.js"></script>
```

doesn't get wiredep into my index.html.

So my question is why grunt wiredep doesn't work on some bower components? The same thing happens to `form.validation` Could anybody shed some light on this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grunt-wiredep` works in a very specific way. The dependencies should be listed in an array inside the `main` property in `bower.josn` like the example you mentioned from bootstrap.

The problem you are facing is probably those packages doesn't have a `main` property or it is using multiple files in a string not an array.

To fix that, you can always define an override for the packages `main` property likes the following ...

In your grunt file:

```
wiredep: {
    ...
    overrides: {
      'package-name': {
        'main': [
          'link-to-css-file.css',
          'link-to-js-file.js'
        ]
      },
    },
},
```

Comment: @Ahmed Alfy - any idea whats happening here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384538/grunt-task-wiredp-is-not-injecting-ngcordova?noredirect=1#comment62335359_37384538