# Grunt & Bower & grunt-wiredep

Tags: gruntjs, bower, grunt-wiredep

I tied to use grunt and bower together. To inject bower components directly to index.html **grunt-wiredep** is used.

But there is one problem, some dependencies that present in bower.json still are not included in *.html

bower.json

```
{
  "name": "***",
  "version": "***",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2.1.1",
    "angular": "1.4.x",
    "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
    ...
  },
  "resolutions": {
    ..
  }
}
```

gruntfile.js

```
....
wiredep: {

      task: {
        src: [
          'app/index.html'
        ],
        options: {
          dependencies: true,
          devDependencies: true          
        }
      }
    }
...
```

index.html

```
...

<!-- bower:js -->
<!-- endbower -->

<!-- bower:css -->
<!-- endbower -->

...
```

In result I haven't included scripts for jquery, angular, bootsrap and css for bootstrap. But some other sources have been included.

The problem is not in *main* property inside *bower.json* as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379477/grunt-wiredep-not-wiring-some-bower-components)

After some investigation, i have found [issue](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2015/06/15/bootstrap-3-3-5-released/) with bootstrap 3.3.x

But *"overrides"* block in my bower.js does not help.

One thing seems to be very interesting: *(the same is for bootstarp)*

after adding

```
"jquery": {
      "main": "D:/REPO/XX/current/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
    }
```

to *overrides* block, *wiredep* has included following to index.html

```
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/D:/REPO/XX/current/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

But when I have wrote `"main": "dist/jquery.js"` it is just ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you have some issue with the structure of your project. Use the `cwd` parameter. I have successfully configured wiredep to add the required dependencies with config:

```
wiredep: {
    task: {
        src: [
            '<%= cfg.webapp_dir %>/index.html'
        ],
        cwd: '.',
        overrides': {
            'bootstrap': {
                'main': ['less/bootstrap.less', 'dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', 'dist/js/bootstrap.min.js']
            }
        },
        fileTypes: {
            html: {
                replace: {
                    js: '<script src="/{{filePath}}"></script>',
                    css: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/{{filePath}}" />'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this also includes bootstrap `overrides` which work flawlessly :)
In my case, the `bower_dependencies` folder is in the same directory that `index.html` is.

Comment: Thx a lot! Problem was actually in project structure. I put bower_dependencies and index.html on the same level - and it helped.

Comment: But it seems quite strange to me, that processed file (`index.html`) and `bower_dependencies`+`bower.json` have to be on the same level. [`cwd` as i can see is path to `bower_dependencies`+`bower.json`]

Comment: I guess it could not be in other dir than your ```index.html``` is. In the end the server needs to serve all the libs that are included in ```bower_components``` and since it also serves the ```index``` file, the path needs to be the same. Unless you want to minify all the libs, in such case (I do it only for production build), you can remove the ```bower_components``` at the end of the building process.