# Grunt task wiredp is not injecting ngcordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, ngcordova

I have the following task writtenm in grunt , which removes ngCordova from index.html. How do I correct it?

```css
// Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
      app: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
        ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
      },
      test: {
        devDependencies: true,
        src: '<%= karma.unit.configFile %>',
        ignorePath:  /\.\.\//,
        fileTypes:{
          js: {
            block: /(([\s\t]*)\/{2}\s*?bower:\s*?(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(\/{2}\s*endbower)/gi,
              detect: {
                js: /'(.*\.js)'/gi
              },
              replace: {
                js: '\'{{filePath}}\','
              }
            }
          }
      }
    },
```

```css
// Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
      }
    },
```

index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/app.css">

    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  
 <!-- <header class="header">
      <h4>welcome</h4>
  </header>-->
  
  <body  ng-app="app">

    
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <div class="container-fluid" ng-view=""></div>
      
      

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <!--this line below gets erased when i run grunt serve or grunt build-->
 <script src="bower_components/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-dynforms/dynamic-forms.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

   <!--  <script src="scripts/ng-cordova.js"></script>-->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script> 

    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
     <script src="scripts/controllers/login.js"></script>
  

    <!-- endbuild -->

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>


 

  </body>

  <!--<footer class="footer footertxt">
    
      
  </footer>-->

</html>
```

Comment: Need to see your index.html file

Comment: Thanks, adding it.

Comment: Just to make sure, you're not statically coding these script tags that you're showing me in-between the bower comment lines?  Also, what's this comment line about `<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->`

Comment: <!-- build:js(src) scripts/vendor.js -->: Any bower's vendor scripts present in bower.json under property dependencies (:warning: not devDependencies) AND located in /bower_components/

<!-- build:js({.tmp/serve,.tmp/partials,src}) scripts/app.js -->: Yours scripts who match with any files located into /src/{app,components}/**/*.{js,es6,ts,coffee}

Comment: yes., its not static

Comment: I downgraded to 0.1.23-alpha from latest an dit works but facing - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435783/yeoman-grunt-not-copying-styles-task issue