# Angulajs-gauge component is in bower.json but doesn't wire over to index.html

Tags: gulp, bower, wiredep, main-bower-files

I have installed angularjs-gauge component using bower. You can see it shows up in my bower.json below

```
 {
  "name": "triangular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "angular": "1.5.8",
    "angular-animate": "1.5.8",
    "angular-cookies": "1.5.8",
    "angular-material": "1.1.1",
    "angular-messages": "1.5.8",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.5.8",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.3.1",
    "angular-translate": "~2.10.0",
    "angular-translate-loader-partial": "~2.10.0",
    "angular-translate-storage-cookie": "~2.10.0",
    "angular-translate-storage-local": "~2.10.0",
    "angular-local-storage": "~0.2.5",
    "angular-digest-hud": "~0.1.13",
    "highlightjs": "^9.2.0",
    "angular-highlightjs": "^0.6.3",
    "angular-dragula": "~1.2.2",
    "angular-chart.js": "0.10.2",
    "angular-google-chart": "~0.1.0",
    "angular-nvd3": "^1.0.8",
    "angular-google-maps": "2.3.2",
    "angular-permission": "^3.2.1",
    "angular-linkify": "~1.2.0",
    "angular-material-data-table": "0.10.9",
    "angular-ui-calendar": "~1.0.1",
    "angular-moment": "~1.0.0-beta.4",
    "animatewithsass": "~3.2.2",
    "countUp.js": "1.6.1",
    "font-awesome": "~4.5.0",
    "material-design-iconic-font": "~2.2.0",
    "weather-icons": "https://github.com/chk1/weather-icons.git#master",
    "textAngular": "~1.5.0",
    "ng-file-upload": "~12.0.1",
    "angular-fixed-table-header": "^0.2.1",
    "angularjs-gauge": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.5.8"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "angular-material": {
      "main": [
        "angular-material.js",
        "angular-material.scss"
      ]
    },
    "weather-icons": {
      "main": [
        "./css/weather-icons.css",
        "./font/*"
      ]
    },
    "angular-dragula": {
      "main": [
        "dist/angular-dragula.js",
        "dist/dragula.min.css"
      ]
    },
    "font-awesome": {
      "main": [
        "./css/font-awesome.css",
        "./fonts/*"
      ]
    },
    "ng-file-upload": {
      "main": [
        "ng-file-upload-shim.js",
        "ng-file-upload.js"
      ]
    }
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.5.8",
    "jquery": "~2.2.1"
  },
  "main": [
    "triangular.js",
    "triangular.css",
    "triangular.scss"
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "README.md"
  ]
}
```

for some reason it shows up here but the  tag never gets created in the index.html file for angularjs-gauge. the others seem to work fine. If I go into my bower_components folder and then click on the bower.json file for the angularjs-gauge component it shows this.

```
   {
        "name": "angularjs-gauge",
        "version": "1.2.0",
        "description": "A Gauge directive for Angular 1.x apps and dashboards",
        "keywords": [
            "angular",
            "gauge",
            "speedometer",
            "js",
            "dial",
            "semi",
            "full",
            "arc"
        ],
        "main": "src/angularjs-gauge.js",
        "authors": ["Ashish Chopra"],
        "license": "MIT",
        "homepage": "https://github.com/ashish-chopra/angular-gauge",
        "ignore": [
        "**/.*",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "test",
        "tests"
      ],
        "dependencies": {
            "angular": "~1.5.8"
        }
    }
```

I tried putting the main element in a list and tried using override as suggested in this post.

[Grunt wiredep not wiring some bower components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379477/grunt-wiredep-not-wiring-some-bower-components)

But every time I ran my gulp tasks it just inserts all the bower components except angularjs-gauge. How do I get it to add the  tag in the index file and not skip over this one?

Comment: did you import the "angularjs-gauge" and add it to module ? sorry you didn't post the code.. just bower.json which is useless to me

Comment: Yes I imported it into my angular app. The issue is when I run my app I get this error : module 'angularjs-gauge' is not available! because when I run my gulp tasks it is supposed on inject the `<script src="../bower_components/angularjs-gauge/src/angularjs-gauge.js></script>` Into my index.html file which it seems to do just fine for all the other components except this one.

Comment: gulp is executed not in web environment so you cannot add it like that you'd  be needing to use require in your gulp script

Comment: sorry I misread your comments, did you inject the script at Head or at body ?

Comment: My gulp script uses gulp-bower with wiredep to wire the components into my angular application. If you look at the bower.json file I am successfully wiring 20+ dependencies into my application with no issues. If you look at the link to the other question I have having the exact same issue but with the angularjs-gauge component instead. It is a gulp/bower issue not an angular/html issue.

Comment: hmm sorry, I never work with wiredep, but I once work with gulp; as far as i can remember while compiling or watching using gulp you could easily require your dependency into your js.. without the need to inject the dependencies script tag into the .html

Answer (score 0):

look at this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bower, haven't tested it but it seems suit you perfectly

Comment: I am using this package to import all of my bower components into my application. For some reason it imports all of the components except angularjs-gauge.